# Is there any way to compress two angles to 2 bytes?

Tags: algorithm, math, bit-manipulation

In my application I often use data which contain two integer angles of spherical coordinates. They are phi (0 <= phi < 360 in degrees), and theta (0 <= theta <= 180 in degrees). Is there any way to compress these angles into 2 bytes? I have found solution which compresses them for 17 bits - it is enough for me, but maybe there any algorithm which allows to compress them for 16 bits? Unfortunately I don't know specific algorithms in such area (like compression theory)

Comment: @RoryDaulton, angles are integer values, which lie in specific range (I mentioned it in question)

Comment: If the angles are given as integers, 360 * 180 = 64800 < 65535, so you can easily "compress" into 16 bits my the multiplication `theta*360+phi`, then "decompress" with the help of modulo and division operators.

Comment: Sneaky: theta can be 180, so it has 181 possible values

Comment: But 181*360 < 65536, so simple multiply-add still works

Comment: @njuffa, It sounds very interesting for me, I definitely should check it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do it: multiply the first angle `phi` by 181, and add the second angle `theta`. The result will fit in an unsigned 16-bit integer:

```
uint16_t compressed = 181 * phi + theta;
```

Given your constraints, the highest number that you are going to get is 65159 (359*181+180), which is barely under 2<sup>16</sup>-1 (65535).

Comment: I cannot believe that it is possible. Let me check this answer!

Comment: 0..359 * 0..180 = 360 * 181 = 65160, still shy of 65535 though.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Right, I missed `<=`. This is fixed now.

Answer (score 5):

If the values of `phi` and `theta` are integers in your ranges, there are 360 possible values of `phi` and 181 possible values of `theta`. You can combine them into a single value between 0 and 65159 with the expression

```
phi * 181 + theta
```

Given a "compressed value of `n` in the range, you can get back the original values with

```
phi = n // 181
theta = n % 181
```

Note that the values will fit into an *unsigned* 16-bit integer, which allows 0 to 65535, but not a signed one without further processing.